# JSF: Returning null in an Action method refreshes only input texts, but not comboboxes

Tags: java, forms, jsf, jsf-1.2

I want to reset my JSF form. I've implemented an `Action` method that resets all properties in the backing bean.

When I return a `String` that forwards to the same page again, all form entries are reset. Input text boxes as well as comboboxes.

But when I return `null` only the input text boxes are reset, not the comboboxes.

I don't understand this behavior. Both ways call the same method, both forward to the same page.

Comment: Which component are you using for comboboxes? A `<h:selectOneMenu>` or something else?

Comment: Think so. Standard JSF component set doesn't have comboboxes at all, OP is perhaps confusing them with dropdown lists.

Comment: Yes, I use `<h:selectOneMenu>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Returning an outcome from an action method causes a new instance of the view (with a new component tree) to be constructed. If you return `null` instead, the existing view instance (the existing component tree) is reused.

Components in JSF are allowed to be stateful. For instance, JSF does not update the model (the backingbean) if validation fails, but still rerenders the invalid data the user entered. This is implemented by keeping the invalid data in the component.